# Discrepancy between Kubernetes node memory usage reported by kubectl top and summed pod memory usage

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I'm facing a discrepancy in memory usage reporting in my Kubernetes cluster, and I'm hoping to gain some insights into what might be causing it.

When I run `kubectl top pods --all-namespaces`, I get the following output listing memory usage for various pods in the cluster:

```
NAMESPACE           NAME                                                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
argocd              argocd-application-controller-0                     40m          185Mi
argocd              argocd-applicationset-controller-584f68b9d7-l954j   1m           51Mi
argocd              argocd-dex-server-8577d9498b-l9lnv                  1m           17Mi
argocd              argocd-notifications-controller-564dcb4995-j582k    1m           25Mi
argocd              argocd-redis-66d9777b78-29mq6                       3m           4Mi
argocd              argocd-repo-server-58c94b5cbf-477v8                 1m           71Mi
argocd              argocd-server-b8bd4f4b5-kz4qw                       1m           41Mi
cert-manager        cert-manager-5b54fc556f-jjsqb                       1m           22Mi
cert-manager        cert-manager-cainjector-7d8b6cf7b9-885vx            1m           26Mi
cert-manager        cert-manager-webhook-7d4744b5ff-cmk98               1m           9Mi
gitlab              gitlab-deployment-66dcd84ffb-b58cs                  133m         6505Mi
kube-system         coredns-6799fbcd5-q7pns                             11m          17Mi
kube-system         local-path-provisioner-84db5d44d9-2466v             1m           7Mi
kube-system         metrics-server-67c658944b-44f5n                     12m          19Mi
kube-system         svclb-traefik-c1466e35-j2psx                        0m           2Mi
kube-system         traefik-5ff9bf948b-bh2bp                            1m           34Mi
linkerd             linkerd-destination-7b5d9869c8-69jwx                8m           63Mi
linkerd             linkerd-identity-7cfd498f58-jpdtr                   3m           24Mi
linkerd             linkerd-proxy-injector-f6c775c9c-wj9cj              3m           27Mi
linkerd-viz         grafana-5646d97bff-n7bj4                            14m          93Mi
linkerd-viz         metrics-api-5f5789c8cf-5mpzp                        2m           29Mi
linkerd-viz         prometheus-6c96bcf74d-85cs9                         25m          154Mi
linkerd-viz         tap-d94cf7688-np8sk                                 5m           29Mi
linkerd-viz         tap-injector-7c5b57889c-h8ft5                       2m           23Mi
linkerd-viz         web-69bbf5b8db-tz9t2                                5m           26Mi
microservice-demo   auth-service-deployment-69dc69b858-7zfl6            7m           543Mi
microservice-demo   backend-api-deployment-786b954f-7kbg4               18m          99Mi
microservice-demo   mongodb-deployment-7d94b89cf5-xs5gs                 12m          288Mi
microservice-demo   payout-service-deployment-7fdf698f68-78zzx          7m           79Mi
microservice-demo   wallet-service-deployment-687fc74bdb-hlh4w          11m          86Mi
microservice-demo   web-app-deployment-5dc5dcbf7c-lz9q8                 1m           7Mi
microservice-demo   wheel-service-deployment-5bfb59d776-nr4pf           4m           67Mi
```

Summing up the memory usage of these pods, the total comes to approximately 9146Mi.

However, when I check the memory usage of the node using kubectl top, it reports a much higher memory usage:

```
NAME      CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
myserver  785m         9%     16508Mi         51%
```

As you can see, the memory usage reported for the node (16508Mi) is significantly higher than the sum of memory usage of the listed pods (9146Mi).

I have verified that the output of kubectl top pods --all-namespaces includes all pods running on the node, so I'm puzzled as to what might be consuming the additional memory reported for the node.

Using `htop` I also don't get any additional information, except the running pods, because `htop` tells me that GitLab is the one that is using the most:
[image]

Could anyone provide insights into why there might be such a discrepancy? What other factors or components could be contributing to the memory usage reported for the node and how I can decrease it. It feels like the whole k3s thing is using way too much memory in total for the clusters that I run. I see people running GitLab on raspberry pi's and stuff, so why is 16GB of RAM not enough?

Answer (score 0):

There are some factors that can be considered on why there is some discrepancies with the memory usage.

1. Resource Overhead: Kubernetes allocates additional memory beyond the requested limits for pods. Might as well that the result for the total memory used includes not just memory consumed by pods but also system processes, kernel etc
2. Cached Memory: Linux kernel caches unused memory for faster allocation when needed. This cached Memory appears in `kubectl top nodes` even though it's not actively used by pods.
3. Buffering: Memory used for buffering I/O operations can also contribute to the overall memory usage reported for the node.
4. Evicted pods: If some pods were recently evicted due to memory pressure, their memory might still reflect on the node's total usage until garbage collection reclaims it.

As a recommendation, you can optimize pod resources requests and limits to ensure that the resource requests are appropriate. Adjusting these values can help in better allocation and management. You can monitor system processes and identify any memory-intensive processes that might be contributing to the overall memory usage. Checking any unnecessary services or components running on the node that could be consuming memory. Evaluate if the current node size is sufficient for the workload running on it. Depending on the workload and resource requirements, you may need to scale up the size to accommodate the memory needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note `kubectl top nodes` is not guaranteed to show memory usage being sum of memory usage displayed by `kubectl top pods`. See the below links for details:

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/193#issuecomment-451309811

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/1060

In particular:

> memory is the sum of the memory usage for the containers in your pod, for pods. For nodes, I believe it's the memory usage as reported by the system-wide node cgroup. So it may include stuff that's not in a pod, IIRC. We just report the information given to us by cadvisor on the node.